# How to get Branch IO url to get his passed parameter and value in android programmatically

Tags: android, branch.io

my branch.io url is "https://example.app.link/fzmLEhobLD"  and i programmatically get this url to retrieve url creation time passed parameter and value through this url.

Comment: above "https://example.app.link/fzmLEhobLD" url is testing url this is not working. plz give any idea for getting url creation time passsed user id without use of first screen onStart() method.

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the parameters programmatically, you would need to use the getLatestReferringParams method. You can call this method anytime after Branch is initialized, which must be in your onStart() method of the Launcher activity:

- https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/android/#read-deep-link

If you do not want to route through the Launcher activity and would like to automatically route directly to the deep link activity, you could also configure specific activities to accept deep links. To learn more about this method, please visit our docs here:

- https://docs.branch.io/pages/deep-linking/routing/#auto-routing-in-android

I hope this helps!